# CloseNotifier for http ResponseWriter

Tags: go

i am using go 1.4.2 and the implementation doesn't seem to have `CloseNotifier` as i want to use it in a long polling handler with something like:

```
func Pollhandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    notify := w.(CloseNotifier).CloseNotify()

    <-notify //should block until the http connection is closed

}
```

is the CloseNotifier not implemented for the http `ResponseWriter`? if so how can i get around this? or is there any implementation for http `ResponseWriter` that implements the `CloseNotifier` interface?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem (after correcting the missing `http.` in your code as @ainar-g notes). How are you testing this?

Comment: @RobNapier by print statement saying cnnection closed after <-notify, the http. part fixed the problem thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`http.CloseNotifier` has been there since [Go 1.1](http://golang.org/doc/go1.1). Your code doesn't work because you forgot the package part:

```
notify := w.(http.CloseNotifier).CloseNotify()
```